# question on struct with char array

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

Below is my code snippet

```
struct encode
{

   char code[MAX];

}a[10];

int main()
{ 
char x[]={'3','0','2','5','9','3','1'};

  for(i=0;i<1;i++)
  {

      printf("%c",x[i]);

//This will printout like 3025931 now I want this to be stored in structure.         
  }

strcpy(a[0].code,x); 
// or 
a[0].code=x;//neither works

display();

}

void display()
{
printf("%c",a[0].code);
}
```

I want the output to be like:3025931.

Which I am not getting due to incompatible assign type. Please tell me where am i going wrong.

Comment: ...what in the name of codethulhu is that `strcopy` supposed to do?

Comment: Why do you have a function called display that you don't even use?

Comment: try using your variable "i" in strcpy(a[i].code, a); instead of hard coding it to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems here. The first is that the source of the `strcpy` is `a` where it probably should be `x`.

The second is that `x` is not null-terminated. Strings in C are null-terminated character arrays.

I would change the two lines:

```
char x[] = {'3','0','2','5','9','3','1'};
strcpy(a[0].code, a);
```

to:

```
char x[] = {'3','0','2','5','9','3','1', '\0'};
strcpy(a[0].code, x);
```

Here's a complete program that gives you what you want (it actually prints out the number twice, once in your inner loop character by character and once with the `printf` so that you can see they're the same):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100
struct encode {
    char code[MAX];
} a[10];

int main() {
    int i, j;
    char x[] = {'3','0','2','5','9','3','1','\0'};

    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            printf("%c", x[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        strcpy(a[0].code, x);
    }
    printf("%s\n",a[0].code);
    return 0;
}
```

*Update based on comment:*

> I am sorry. I am new to C. My apologies for not pasting the code snippet correctly in the beginning: "printf("%c",a[0].code);" doesn't display "3025931".

No, it won't. That's because `a[0].code` is a character array (string in this case) and you should be using `"%s"`, *not* `"%c"`. Changing the format specifier in the `printf` should fix that particular issue.

Comment: ...and of course that new intialisation of `x` could be equivalently written as `char x[] = "3025931";`

Comment: I am sorry I am new to 'c' my apologise for not pasting the code snippet correctly in the begining..

void display()
{
printf("%c",a[0].code);
}
 doesnt display "3025931"

Comment: paxdiablo thanks for your answers.. what if i am dealing with int array like 
struct encode {
    int code[MAX];
} a[10];
int x[]={'3','0','2','5','9','3','1'}; 

should I use strcpy after converting from int[] to char[]?

Comment: Then you cannot treat the array as a string, you must process the int elements one-by-one. I'm not sure exactly *what* you're trying to achieve. It may be better to ask a separate question on how to do it (with no preconceived notions) rather than how to modify this existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

`strcpy(a[0].code, a);`

did you mean

`strcpy(a[0].code, x);`

...?

Also, `x` needs to be null terminated, or you need to replace `strcpy` with `strncpy` or `memcpy` and pass in a length.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make much sense:

```
   strcpy(a[0].code, a);
```

Perhaps you want this:

```
    memcpy(a[0].code, x, sizeof x);
    a[0].code[sizeof x] = '\0';
```

(The second line is necessary to nul-terminate `code`, making it a proper C string).

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things are wrong in your program. The most offending line is this:

```
strcpy(a[0].code, a);
```

but there are other oddities as well, e.g.

- display is never called
- a is only assigned (kind of), but never read (except in display, which is never called)
- the i loop makes no sense

Basically, this program looks like copy-pasted by someone who has no clue.

Comment: "Basically, this program looks like copy-pasted by someone who has no clue." Is that necessary?

Comment: ChaosPandion: a fact is a fact

Comment: BTW, the OP has been heavily edited, it was worse in the beginning