# I have same struct question for int array

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct

paxdiablo gave the previous answer for it working with char array.. can I know how to work with int array for the same below code?

LIke:

```
struct encode {
    int code[MAX]; //instead char code[MAX]
} a[10];

int main() {
    int i, j;
    int x[] = {3,0,2,5,9,3,1};
    //instead char x[] = {'3','0','2','5','9','3','1','\0'};
    for(i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            printf("%d", x[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        a[0].code=x;
        //strcpy(a[0].code, x); for char

    }
    printf("%d\n",a[0].code);
    //printf("%s\n",a[0].code); for char
    return 0;
}
```

Like show can this be done for int array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the type of `a[0].code`?  Is it an `int`?  When you print it with `%d` as format, what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: If you can't fix the exact same issue without running back for help, I'm not sure you're cut out to be a programmer.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I didn't understand a thing.

Comment: no im dealing with int array a[0].code is int code[MAX]. When I print with %d would like the output to be "3025931". I am pretty new with c I would like to learn.  above same code works for char array which is commented. Now I want to store int array in structure and display its content.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Refer answer from your previous Question [question on struct with char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911401/question-on-struct-with-char-array)

- Use `memcpy` to copy the integer
  array elements.
- use `%d` in case you want to print
  integers.

Comment: I only asked the previous question in the link.. memcpy with %d prints out the memory and not the inter array. Is there anything I am missing.?

Comment: Yes. Thats why I asked to refer the answer and use memcpy instead of strcpy for copying integers.

Answer (score 0):

Some questions for you, all the snippets below are from your code:

1. In the following, what's the type of `x[j]`.  What type does `%c` expect?

   ```
   printf("%c", x[j]);
   ```
2. What's the type of `a[0].code` below?  It's an array, with a predefined memory allocated to it.  What to you expect the above statement to do?

   ```
   a[0].code=x;
   ```
3. Again, what is the type of `a[0].code`?  What does `%d` format expect?

   ```
   printf("%d\n",a[0].code);
   ```

The answers to all the questions above are easy, or should be available in any text book.

*Programming doesn't work by trial-and-error*.  You should find a good reference and a good textbook, and think about what you're doing.

As a first step, please answer the questions I have asked above, and hopefully you will be able to fix most of your mistakes yourself.

Comment: Thanks Alok. It my mistake in "%d " and not "%c" & a[0].code type is 'int' but x is also int while compiling a[0].code=x; gives 
 "incompatible types in assignment". I used memcpy(encd[k].code, c, sizeof c); but the result value for printf("%d",a[0].code); give 8731424 which is memory and not "3025931" which I am expecting. i worked with char[] which gives the required result.. but when int array doesnt give the same result. 

This is what i need int x[]={3,2,4,5,6} store it in struct and display back like "32456". Thanks I will change the original snippet which is cofusing.

Comment: `a[0].code` is not `int` because you declared it as an *array of `int`s*!  Please try to answer the questions based on your code, not based upon what you want them to be.